# What is the $\min\left(\sum_{i=1}^nf\left(x_i\right)\right)$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, optimization, summation, convex-analysis

How do you prove that if $f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is a convex-concave function (concave for $x<a$  and convex for $x\ge a$ for a certain value of $a\in \mathbb{R}$) and $x_1,x_2,...,x_n \in \Re$ such that  $x_1+x_2+...+x_n=0$ then $\min\left(\sum_{i=1}^nf\left(x_i\right)\right)$ (if exists) is when

$x_1=x_2=...=x_n$ with $x_i \in$ convex part of  $f$ (for   $i \in \mathbb{N} : 0<i<n+1$)

or when $x_1 \neq x_2=x_3=...=x_n$ with $x_1 \in$ concave part of  $f$ and $x_k \in$ convex part of  $f $ (for   $k\in \mathbb{N} : 1<k<n+1$ ) ?

I mean why isn't it possible that more than one $x_j \in$ concave part of  $f$ (for   $j\in \mathbb{N} : 0<j<n+1$ ) ?

Comment: Please accept my answer or indicate what is missing.

Answer (score 0):

Let $x^*$ be an optimal solution, and assume that $x_j^*$ and $x_k^*$ are in the (interior of the) concave part of the domain of $f$. Consider the subproblem $\min \{ f(x_j) + f(x_k) : x_j + x_k = x_j^* + x_k^*, \; x_j, x_k \in Df_{concave} \}$. By assumption, $x_j^*$ and $x_k^*$ are optimal to this subproblem. Since the minimum of a concave function occurs at an extreme point of the domain, there is another optimal solution where $x_j$ is at the inflection point and $x_k$ is in the concave part of the domain with the same optimal objective value.